# Exception when I try to load file, unable to read beyond the end of the stream

Tags: c#, excel, excellibrary

I try to read an RTF file and send text for this to Excel file. I do this:

```
Byte[] rtf;
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("/1.RTF"), 
    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    int size = Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length);
    rtf = new Byte[size];
    stream.Read(rtf, 0, size);
};

textx = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(rtf);

string file = @"C:\Users\ITS_prog\Desktop\newdoc.xls";
Workbook workbook = Workbook.Load(file);
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];
worksheet.Cells[0, 1] = new Cell((short)1);
worksheet.Cells[2, 0] = new Cell(9999999);
worksheet.Cells[3, 3] = new Cell((decimal)3.45);
worksheet.Cells[2, 2] = new Cell(textx);
worksheet.Cells[2, 4] = new Cell("Second string");
worksheet.Cells[4, 0] = new Cell(32764.5, "#,##0.00");
worksheet.Cells[5, 1] = new Cell(DateTime.Now, @"YYYY-MM-DD");
worksheet.Cells.ColumnWidth[0, 1] = 3000;
workbook.Save(file);
```

But in this row, `Workbook workbook = Workbook.Load(file);` my app give the exception:

> Exception unable to read beyond the end of the stream.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: @AxelKemper I'm using ExcelLibrary. I can't use  Excel Interop, I haven't excel on server

Comment: Can you open the file in question with `Excel` (or some other program capable to read `Excel` files) to show that the file is consistent?

Comment: @AxelKemper it is empty. It have only two empty sheets. If i didn't read rtf file, I would write data to excel.

Comment: Can't you just read the file with `string text = File.ReadAllText(path, encoding)`?

Comment: To create an empty `Workbook` ready to receive your data, just use `Workbook workbook = new Workbook();`. After filling in the data, you `save` it to a file as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928740/excellibrary-documentation)

Comment: @AxelKemper I did it  `Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
workbook = Workbook.Load(file);` but it doesn't work too

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I tried did it: `string rtfText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("/1.RTF"), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8); Workbook workbook = new Workbook(); workbook = Workbook.Load(file);` but it doesn't work too

Comment: You cannot load an empty (zero bytes) file. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. How do you intend to interprete the RTF contents? Creating the empty Workbook and writing it to file should work.

Comment: @AxelKemper I must add infromation from rtf file, to existent excel file( If I can do new file of course I do it. Excel file it is not empty.

Comment: RTF files are text files with formatting information. To read RTF, you are going to need a suitable tool or library. Otherwise, you cannot extract data from RTF files. Excellibrary is only capable of reading/writing Excel files, not RTF files.

Comment: can You advise me some free library for decision this task?